# Find one's bearings

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, expressions, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

**Find one's bearings:**

To recognize or determine one's orientation, position, or abilities relative to one's surroundings or situation:

**Example:**

> - It took me a little while to find my bearings in the new office, but after a week, I felt as if I'd been working there for years. [Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/find+(one%27s)+bearings)

Please let me know which construction is preferred here and why:

> - Why do you insist so much?! I don't want to  change my field of work. I think I've paid my dues at this job and I'm just ...................It's time to enjoy all my efforts during these many years. 
>   ***a.* finding** my bearings. 
>   ***b.* beginning to find** my bearings.

They both sound correct to me here, but I need to know how a native speaker thinks on them.

Comment: Either expression is grammatical, but neither fits the situation. "Finding bearings" is something that happens as one is beginning to do a job, not after "many years".

Comment: But here I think "find one's bearings" is something like "find oneself" @Jack O'Flaherty. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think you are wrong about that. "finding one's bearings" is a short-term process that takes place when one is in a new situation. A googled definition: "figure out one's position or situation relative to one's surroundings." And an example from M-W: "Our course for new employees will help you get/find your bearings at work."

Comment: In fact, your own example speaks of "a week".

Comment: I think you may be trying to say something more like “Mastering my craft”.